# Angular JS: One function in the controller is reached , other is not - from view during instantiation of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a modal view(.jsp) that has integrated directive (named as **'querybuilder', Yellow part in the picture** - a js file). Controller(named as 'addEditRuleSetCtrl') and  directive is included from upper level and inclusion seems fine. We have initiated the directive from the view as :

```
<query-builder group="addEditRuleSetCtrl.filter.group"
                       ruleConditionOperators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getRuleConditionOperators()"
                       fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                       ></query-builder>
```

**Now the problem, I am seeing is 'addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()' works fine (reaches controller , maps data to 'field' and hence the associated dropdown field displays right data) but looks like 'addEditRuleSetCtrl.getRuleConditionOperators()' does not even reach the function defined inside the controller (I have an window.alerm() inside the function in the controller that does not show up)and hence the associted dropdown is empty (In the screenshot , it is pointed by the upside arrow).
We are using angularjs 1.4.4 and java 1.8**

Below are the details of the description , Here is my JSP-view, directive and controller:

**Modal view (This is a JSP file and this includes the template, used by the directive):**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link 
    href="<c:url value='aviato/ruleEngine/addEditRuleSet/css/addeditruleset.css' />"
    rel="stylesheet">
</link>

<%--<script src="aviato/ruleEngine/addEditRuleSet/directive/addEditRuleSet_directive.js"></script>--%>

<form name="addEditRuleSetModalForm" novalidate class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                {{addEditRuleSetCtrl.windowHeader}}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right"
                        ng-click="addEditRuleSetCtrl.close()" data-toggle="uibtooltip" title="Cancel" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
                </button>
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            Hello world [origin] : {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.origin }}
            <br />
            Hello world [iceField] : {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.iceField }}
            ahahahhaahahahahaahahhg1111!!!!! {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.output }}

            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Example Output</strong><br>
                <%--<span ng-bind-html="addEditRuleSetCtrl.output"></span>--%>
                ahahahhaahahahahaahahhg!!!!! {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.output }}
            </div>

            <query-builder group="addEditRuleSetCtrl.filter.group"
                           ruleConditionOperators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getRuleConditionOperators()"
                           fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                           ></query-builder>



        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addEditRuleSetCtrl.test()" data-toggle="tooltip" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" ></span></button><span></span>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/queryBuilderDirective.html">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <select ng-options="o.operator as o.name for o in ruleConditionSetOperators" ng-model="group.operator" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addCondition()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Condition</button>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Group</button>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Remove Group</button>
        </div>
        <div class="group-conditions">
            <div ng-repeat="rule in group.rules | orderBy:'index'" class="condition">
                <div ng-switch="rule.hasOwnProperty('group')">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                        <query-builder group="rule.group"></query-builder>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default">
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                            <%--<select style="margin-left: 5px" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in ruleConditionOperators" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm"></select>--%>
                            <select style="margin-left: 5px" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in ruleConditionOperators" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                            <input style="margin-left: 5px" type="text" ng-model="rule.data" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeCondition($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**The Directive: ( This is a .js file. If I uncomment 'scope.ruleConditionOperators' here, the red-arrow-pointed dropdown displays data)**

```
AddEditRuleSetApp.directive('queryBuilder', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        group: '=',
        ruleConditionOperators: '=',
        fields: '='

    },
    templateUrl: '/queryBuilderDirective.html',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var content, directive;
        content = element.contents().remove();
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {


            scope.ruleConditionSetOperators = [
                { name: 'AND' },
                { name: 'OR' }
            ];

           /* scope.ruleConditionOperators = [
                { name: '=' },
                { name: '<>' },
                { name: '<' },
                { name: '<=' },
                { name: '>' },
                { name: '>=' }
            ];*/

            scope.addCondition = function () {
                scope.group.rules.push({
                    condition: '=',
                    field: 'Firstname',
                    data: ''
                });
            };

            scope.removeCondition = function (index) {
                scope.group.rules.splice(index, 1);
            };

            scope.addGroup = function () {
                scope.group.rules.push({
                    group: {
                        operator: 'AND',
                        rules: []
                    }
                });
            };

            scope.removeGroup = function () {
                "group" in scope.$parent && scope.$parent.group.rules.splice(scope.$parent.$index, 1);
            };

            directive || (directive = $compile(content));

            element.append(directive(scope, function ($compile) {
                return $compile;
            }));
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

**The Controller:**

```
AddEditRuleSetApp.controller( 'AddEditRuleSetModalController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$uibModalInstance','RuleEngineService', 'origin', 'iceField',
    function( $scope, $rootScope , $uibModalInstance, RuleEngineService, origin, iceField )
        {
            var self = this;
            self.origin = origin;
            self.iceField = iceField;

            self.data = '{"group": {"operator": "AND","rules": []}}';
            self.output = 'bologna';

            self.fieldsDDE = [
                { name: 'FirstnameDDE' },
                { name: 'LastnameDDE' },
                { name: 'BirthdateDDE' },
                { name: 'CityDDE' },
                { name: 'CountryDDE' }
            ];

            self.fieldsATT = [
                { name: 'FirstnameATT' },
                { name: 'LastnameATT' },
                { name: 'BirthdateATT' },
                { name: 'CityATT' },
                { name: 'CountryATT' }
            ];


            self.ruleConditionOperators = [
                { name: '=' },
                { name: '<>' },
                { name: '<' },
                { name: '<=' },
                { name: '>' },
                { name: '>=' }
            ];


            self.clientChanged = function( selCleintId )
            {
                self.getAllMachinesForClientForDuplication( self.duplicateClient );
                self.displayErrorMessages = false;
            }


            self.getRuleConditionOperators = function()
            {
                window.alert("--------*******---------Reached client side controller to getAllRuleConditionOperators");
                return self.ruleConditionOperators;
               /* RuleEngineService.getAllRuleConditionOperators( )
                    .then(
                        function( d )
                        {
                            self.ruleConditionOperators = d;
                        },
                        function( errResponse )
                        {
                            console.error( 'Error while fetching rule-condition-operators' );
                        }
                    );
*/
            };


            self.htmlEntities = function(str)
            {
                return String(str).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            };
            //self.output = null;


            self.displayErrorMessages = false;
            self.createSuccess = '';
            self.createHeader = '';
            self.backendErr = "";

            self.windowHeader = "Create/Edit Rule Group";


            self.close = function()
            {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            self.getCorrespondingFields = function()
            {
               // window.alert("---------------Reached client side controller to getCorrespondingFields");
                return self.origin == 'DDE' ? self.fieldsDDE : self.fieldsATT;
            };

            self.computed = function(group)
            {
                window.alert("Inside controller: computed");

                if (!group) return "";
                for (var str = "(", i = 0; i < group.rules.length; i++) {
                    i > 0 && (str += " <strong>" + group.operator + "</strong> ");
                    str += group.rules[i].group ?
                        self.computed(group.rules[i].group) :
                        group.rules[i].field + " " +
                        //htmlEntities(group.rules[i].condition)
                        group.rules[i].condition
                        + " " + group.rules[i].data;
                }

                return str + ")";
            };

            //self.json = null;

            self.filter = JSON.parse(self.data);


            $scope.$watch('filter', function (newValue)
            {
                self.output = self.computed(newValue);

            }, true);

            self.test = function()
            {
                window.alert(JSON.stringify( self.filter) );
            };

        } 
    ]);
```

The screenshot:

[image: (]

Comment: In your html, change `ruleConditionOperators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getRuleConditionOperators()"` to `rule-condition-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getRuleConditionOperators()"` in the part were you add the directive in the DOM

Comment: Thnks Alon. It worked